# Bullet Point is on my Nav menu

Tags: html, css

I made a site and just did the navbar. On Google its good only the underline is there but on Firefox the bullet points are still there how do I fix this. Also how do I get ride of the underlines?

Comment: Set up a jsFiddle file so we can see the HTML and CSS that you are using.

Comment: Post your code. But you probably need something like text-decoration: none; list-style: none; If it still doesn't update, you might need to clear your cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Let say: your nav has container: #nav, then:

```
 #nav a {
      list-style-type:none;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your `navbar`'s css:

```
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration:none;
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) is a reference from MDN. It has everything about list styling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use as CSS reset sheet: [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)

And then for your nav bar:

```
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

It would help if we had your code though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like `text-decoration: none; list-style: none;` inside your `nav` `ul` tag

Answer (score -2):

on css:

```
*{
text-decoration: none; 
list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Why are you applying this to ALL elements?

Comment: Because it's a best practise cliear off css styled rules before beginning programming. So you won't encounter problem like border images on Ie, list styling on Firefox and Opera ecc. If he has to put another list in his site he will get the same problem with your code.

Comment: hmm if you want to do something like that use reset.css

Comment: Exactly, you would use a CSS Reset. The OP is clearly only asking for his nav list friend

Comment: That's true, i just suggested clearing what he needed. -2 for this, ahah thanks guys, really smart

Comment: And for suggesting to use css reset, I got a -1. Awesome @SBO